# How to make GSAP timeline recognize elements that are created in the middle of it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, timeline, paperjs, gsap

Here is the Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVoQzX

Im trying to animate and add path elements on the go. Once the last animation has finished i'm adding new path point which id like to animate. Unfortunately timeline cant find the element, is there a way to force GSAP recognize newly crated elements?

Timeline and paperjs code:

```
var path = new paper.Path({
  strokeColor: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 3,
});

path.add(new paper.Point(100, 100));
path.add(new paper.Point(150, 150));

function extrapath() {
    path.add(new paper.Point(path.lastSegment.point.x, path.lastSegment.point.y));
}
var tm = new TimelineMax();
    tm.to($(path.segments[1].point), speed, 
    {x:path.lastSegment.point.x+10, y:path.lastSegment.point.y+25}, 0)

    .add( function(){ extrapath(); })

    .to($(path.segments[2].point), speed, 
    {x:path.lastSegment.point.x+10, y:path.lastSegment.point.y+25}, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the time you define your animation, `path.segments[2]` doesn't exist because path only have 2 segments.
One solution would be to create all needed segments before triggering the animation.
But if you really want to modify the path after the first animation ended and use the modified path in a second animation, you can use `TimelineMax` `onComplete` callback ([documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax)) to split your code in 2 distinct animations.
Here is the updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJLaJv).

```
// init path with 2 segments
var path = new Path({
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 3
});
path.add(new Point(100, 100));
path.add(new Point(300, 300));

var speed = 1;
// trigger first segment animation and set second animation as a callback
new TimelineMax({ onComplete: animation2 }).to(path.firstSegment.point, speed, { x: path.firstSegment.point.x + 100, y: path.firstSegment.point.y + 100 });
function animation2() {
    // add segment
    path.add(path.lastSegment.point);
    // trigger second animation
    new TimelineMax().to(path.lastSegment.point, speed, { x: path.lastSegment.point.x + 50, y: path.lastSegment.point.y - 50 });
}
```